# Android TabLayout class not resolving

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-tablayout, material-components-android

I cannot get TabLayout to resolve.  I've tried implementing all the dependencies others have recommended for this issue, but it's still not working.  Can anyone help?  Is the issue that I'm trying to use older features alongside Androidx? Thanks

SECTION ONE:
build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.instagramclone"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    //Design
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:30.0.0'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:30.0.0"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:2.0.4'
    implementation "com.android.support:design:30.0.0"

}
```

SECTION TWO: XML FILE

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width='match_parent'
            android:layout_height = 'wrap_content'>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:background="@drawable/white_grey_border_bottom">

            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</merge>
```

Comment: Clean , rebuild , clearCache of gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support libraries v.`30.0.0` **don't** exist.

Remove these dependencies:

```
//Design
//implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:30.0.0'
//implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:30.0.0"
//implementation "com.android.support:design:30.0.0"
```

For the `TabLayout` add this dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

and use the class `com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Gabriele suggested, you can further add tabs in your XML file like

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="match_parent">

     <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
             android:text="@string/tab_text"/>

     <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
             android:icon="@drawable/ic_android"/>

 </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

Or, if you want to add them programmatically,
In your onCreate, do something like this,

```
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));
```

Comment: Nice!  Thanks for the tips!